# How to make something say in python

Tags: python, text-to-speech, speaker

I want my python program to say
like

```
a = "Hello Boss I am your program"
say(a)
#and it should say the text
```

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first you need to install module named PYTTSX3.

do pip/pip3 install PYTTSX3

then code is here:

```
import PYTTSX3 as speaker
tts = speaker.init()

def say(text):
   tts.say(text)
   tts.runAndWait()

a = "Hello Boss I am your program"
say(a)
```

This will read aloud 'Hello Boss I am your program'
;)